# Passing a parameter to a JavaScript transformation in MarkLogic

Tags: javascript, marklogic, transformation, marklogic-9, mlcp

I have a JavaScript transformation where I take a csv and load it into db using MLCP. Say that my function accepts content and context. I have 2 other parameters that I need to pass through MLCP so that I can use it in the transformation.
Can I use -transform_param "my-value" in this case? How do I write the function?

I am hard coding the values as of now instead of passing them as a parameter.

```
function test(content, context, param1, param2)
{
//use param1 and param2
}
//export
```

Is this the right implementation?

Expectation: Use the transformation to use on other documents.
Reality: Hard coding the values to be used.

Answer (score 2):

Check [this example](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/mlcp/import#id_14809).

The context variable should contain your parameter.

```
function yourTransformation(content, context)
{
  const propVal = (context.transform_param == undefined)
                 ? "UNDEFINED" : context.transform_param;

  ...
};
```

Comment: I'm passing transform_param the value that I want to give to propVal. In my transformation I have "var colA = newDoc.propVal" and then I am using my colA in URI. It's still not working. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Could you please post the code of your transformation?

Comment: I've fixed it using the function call in the transformation and passing the parameters there for now.